# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to copy either an integer or a dictionary, using the same line of code. I need 2 instances of the integer/dict.

My line of code is something like:

```
dict['item1'] = dict['item2'].copy
```

However, when it's an integer, I get this:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Any idea what the cause is?

Comment: use the `copy.copy` method from the copy module rather than a method access on the item?

Comment: Note that you are not *calling* `.copy` either, even if `dict['item2']` were a dictionary instead of an integer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all objects have a `copy` method like `dict` does.  Fortunately, there's [`copy.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy), which will copy anything you pass it.

Answer (score 12):

use the `copy` method from the [`copy` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) rather than a method access on the item.

```
import copy

dict['item1'] = copy.copy(dict['item2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `copy.deepcopy(dict)` method

```
import copy
some_dict = {'a':'aaa', 'b':1}
new_dict['b'] = copy.deepcopy(some_dict['a'])
```

Comment: Why use `copy.deepcopy` instead of `copy.copy`?

Comment: @Virtualxtc The deepcopy is the "extended" version of the copy, which create copies of the mutable objects, at the same time the copy method do not copy mutable objects and simply pass their value by reference, you can read more here: https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/

Answer (score 0):

Or use `int(...)`:

```
dict['item1'] = int(dict['item2'])
```

So it would be as expected.